# Making h:outputtext don't print a line break on a jsf page

Tags: jsf, formatting

I have some code like the below and it works, but instead of showing just a number, I want to show "number%". Here's what I have:

```
<h:outputtext value="#{somebean.doubleValue}">
    <f:convertnumber maxfractiondigits="2">
</h:outputtext>
```

If I put the "%" sign inside the value property, the converter won't work (I believe because the evaluated result is not just a number), but if I put the "%" sign in other outputtext tag, one line break appears between the number and it. I don't want that.

```
<h:outputtext value="#{somebean.doubleValue}">
    <f:convertnumber maxfractiondigits="2">
</h:outputtext>
<h:outputtext value="%"> <!--prints a new line-->
```

What's the best way to achieve a "xx.xx%" formatting on jsf?

Comment: Why do you want to use `h:outputtext` to display just "%"? Just put % after the first one.

Comment: @Bhesh: That yields the same effect. Apparently the OP is using it in some narrow table cell or something whose contents just get word-wrapped which visually appears as a linebreak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the CSS `white-space` property of the common parent element to `nowrap`.

E.g.

```html
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <h:outputText value="#{somebean.doubleValue}">
        <f:convertNumber maxfractiondigits="2">
    </h:outputText>%
</span>
```

*(note: you don't necessarily need `<h:outputText>` for plain text)*

If you are actually using this in a `<h:column>` (as I would initially guess), you could specify a classname for the `<td>` by the `columnClasses` attribute of the `<h:dataTable>`.

Comment: Hmm, I believe this should work. I'm not near my development machine right now so I'll come back later if I have any problems. Thanks!